# How do I make my ionic buttons "slimmer"?

Tags: css

I've been using the developer tools to try and make the ionic button "pill-like", so that the button is narrow.  A close example would be like the buttons on stack overflow, such as the "Ask Question" button.  There is not much spacing on the top and bottom of the text.

How can I achieve that effect with my buttons?  Here's a codepen that shows the button I'm trying to modify:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKPdey

```
 <button class="button button-small button-calm">
         hello I'm a small button
    </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override `padding` and `min-height`:

```
.button.button-small.button-calm {
  min-height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Here is a [codepan fork](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKPdJy)

If that's still not enough, change the `line-height`:

```
.button.button-small.button-calm {
  line-height: 100%; /* play with this to fit your needs */
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot!  for some reason this isn't working in my project, but its working fine on codepen.  i'll keep working on it.  thx a lot